# using custom CSS classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Now, If I do:

```
<div class="metanav"> 
...
</div>
```

Then everything inside the div will have the style `.metanav` applied to it.

However, if I copy paste `.metanav` in the CSS and name the new one as `A`; then change the div's class to be:

```
<div class="A">
```

then it's not doing anything.

My css code is:

```
.metanav        { text-align: right; font-size: 0.8em; padding: 0.3em;
                  margin-bottom: 1em; background: #fafafa; }
.A              { text-align: right; font-size: 0.8em; padding: 0.3em;
                  margin-bottom: 1em; background: #fafafa; }
```

Why do I miss here?

Comment: Could you post your css code?

Comment: @camccar I added the css code.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u4mg6hk3/

Comment: There used to be a rule for ids & classname where first caracter should not be be an upper case letter nor a number. Your browser might still follow that rule and skip this classname seen as not valid. Which browser do you use and which OS ? give a test with an a class instead A to put this possibility aside ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus actually i add other names, such as "mmm" and they didn't work either.

Comment: I am using flask, not sure this is relevant here.

Comment: did you reload both HTML & CSS file after modification (also emptied the browser's cache) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the . before A?

Should look like this:

```
.A {
border-style: inset;
border-width: 5px;
}
```